# Deploying Next13 App only render 404 page not found when trying to access any path

Tags: next.js, deployment, production, next.js13

Please can someone tell me why I'm getting an error 404 when I tried to access any of my app route, even the "/"?

[image]

I build the project with npm build and setting up my docker things... then I launch the container, as you can see in the logs, The npm start launch correctly, and the container has the following folder:

- .next ( which contains all the app path, I checked that on my own )
- node_modules
- public

I'm using:

- Next13 with the app directory

I expected after the launch that the app will work perfectly fine, I did some research but found nothing in the end.

Comment: It was a Nextjs App directory bug, It's corrected now.

Comment: Can you please provide a solution instead of only saying that now works?

Comment: @alch_coder As I say it was an internal next Bug, they seem to have corrected it in their latest release.